# Constrain to any 2 axes during transform?

Tags: modeling, transforms

I want to be able to lock my translation/scale operations to two axes at a time, say xy, xz or yz. It currently takes two operations (one for each axis).

Example, say for a cylinder, I would like to reduce the radius. I currently have to scale on the x axis first, then on the y axis, or I have to manually input the scale values in the object properties panel.

This option is easily accessible in 3dsmax via the axis constraints command bar. Or I can click the intersecting area between the 3d manipulator of the axes in question and move in that plane.

Answer (score 39):

While Blender doesn't have widgets to do this, its fairly straightforward.

- Using the Manipulator: Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on the Grab/Scale handles,
  X locks `YZ`,
  Y locks `XZ`,
  Z locks `XY`
- Using Transform keys: Grab with <kbd>G</kbd> or Scale with <kbd>S</kbd>,
  <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> locks `YZ`,
  <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> locks `XZ`,
  <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> locks `XY`

As @sambler notes, you can do <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Shift X,X</kbd> move along the objects *Local* YX axis, works for any axis of course.

Comment: The keyboard shortcuts also carry through to local transforms eg Shift X twice will lock on YZ local axes.

Comment: ...and three times will lock to the view's x axis ;-) Essentially, typing an axis after starting a transform cycles through the Global, Local, and View coordinate systems in that order. So if you press `g` `xxxx` it will constrain to the global x-axis.