# Make a ring larger but same thickness

Tags: modeling, workflow, transforms

Is it possible to make a ring larger, but maintain the same thickness?

I only selected the vertices of the ring, the ring is part of a larger object and I don't want to separate it.

If I simply scale it with <kbd>S</kbd>, it becomes thicker as well.

Comment: There is no obvious way to do this without detaching the object, as far as I can see. Could you post some images of the objects in question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constrain to any 2 axes during transform?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7491/constrain-to-any-2-axes-during-transform)

Answer (score -1):

Try scaling in the y axis how much you want, then scale the same in the x axis. (Example with things you type: <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd> `90`, <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd> `90`)