# How Do I Shrink/Fatten Selected Along The X Axis?

Tags: modeling, workflow, selection-tools

I would have to select the shrink/fatten tool in tools or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. I did, but it only shrink/fattens along the `Y` axis, but not the `X` axis and it is really peeving me off.

Comment: Make sure Pivot point is not set to Individual Origins (set it to something else, e.g Median Point with Ctrl+Coma). Also please add some screenshots to your questions, guessing is always something preventing success.

Comment: Shrink/fatten 'scales' based on the normals. A standard scale `S` can be restricted to a single axis. You can also [scale on only two axes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7492/935).

Comment: did you scale the whole object outside of Edit mode? if yes, go back to Object mode, hit CTRL+A and select Scale

Answer (score 1):

Press the corresponding button on the keyboard to tell Blender which axis you want to use, namely: `X`,`Y` or `Z`. Select the faces you want to scale, press <kbd>S</kbd> and press <kbd>X</kbd> to scale along the `X` axis.