# snap to the ground/grid

Tags: snapping

I have a sphere and it's floating ( not on ground level). I simply want to snap it back to the ground (grid). I select 'increment' in snap option and turn on **absolute grid snap**. Then i move the sphere while holding ctrl (SNAP ON) , it will snap but not snapping to the ground/grid. Anyone can help ? i use Blender 2.8.2

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7491/constrain-to-any-2-axes-during-transform

Comment: its 2.82 or more likely 2.82a.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos not the one i'm looking for. Imagine you're in perspective view and want to move the object using G or using transform gizmo and need to snap at specific grid point.

Comment: Maybe origin issues? Would be easier with a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you mean, you wish **the bottom** of your sphere object to touch exactly the grid, as if it "felt" on a virtual ground (that doesn't exist).

To achieve this, you need to *tell* blender *exactly* what you mean by *bottom*, unfortunately. I.e., you need to (temporarily) move the *origin* of your sphere to the object's mesh feature you wish blender *snaps* everywhere, even to the grid.

E.g. you need to go into **edit mode**, select only the bottom (vertex?) of your mesh,

[image]

then go back to **object mode**, and select "Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D cursor"

[image]

After doing so, the **snap** command referred to the **absolute grid snap**

[image]

will allow you to *exactly* snap the (temporary) origin of your object as you wish.

[image]

Then you can *restore* the origin of your object using another option from the same menu above, i.e. "Origin to Geometry"

If you had a "floor" object like a plane or else, you could maybe use a **rigid body** simulation to let your sphere fell onto the "floor", but that requires much more setup for a simple task like this, although it could be useful though to let  as series of objects (e.g. tree shaped objects) to fell onto another one (e.g. a mountain shaped big object) instead of placing them manually...

The rigid body simulation will also be quite real, and your object would need to sit perfectly on the floor or, as maybe in the ICOsphere above, it would roll on a side, etc. Not recommended in this case.

I hope this answers you.